# Using CSS to transition the fill property of an SVG path on hover

Tags: css, svg, hover, css-transitions

I'm including an SVG image file on my page within an `object` tag, like this:

```
<object type="image/svg+xml" data="linkto/image.svg">
   <!-- fallback image in CSS -->
</object>
```

The image in question is a world map, i want to transition the `fill` property when the mouse hovers over a `group`, in this case I've grouped my SVG by continent, so South America looks something like this:

```
<g id="south_america">
    <path fill="#FAFAFA" d="(edited for brevity)"/>
</g>
```

I can get the `fill` property to change on hover by using the following CSS at the top of my SVG document:

```
<style>
#south_america path {
    transition: fill .4s ease;
}
#south_america:hover path {
    fill:white;
}
</style>
```

But I can't get the `fill` colour to fade in with a CSS transition, the colour just changes instantly, can anyone shed light on this please?

Comment: This might have to do with you setting the original fill via the fill attribute in the HTML, and setting the hover fill via the CSS, but I'll have to do some tests to be sure. **A [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) would really help.**

Comment: Hmm interesting, I didn't consider that, I'll look a little deeper, here's a fiddle in the meantime: http://jsfiddle.net/YLs6B/

Comment: Here's a fiddle where `#europe` seems to be working: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/superscript18/YLs6B/1/).  Also, `#south_america` doesn't exist in the fiddle you gave me.

Comment: @DavidAlsbright #south_america has the id #south-america in that fiddle. Same for north_america. If you change the id to use the "_" it selects the americas

Answer (score 160, accepted):

**In order to transition/fade, CSS needs a starting value and an ending value.**
Because you set the color for the path using the SVG attribute `fill="#FAFAFA"`, CSS doesn't process it and the transition doesn't fade.

Instead if you use CSS to set the color, the transition will behave as expected

So all I had to do to make the transition work is give the `#europe` a starting fill to transition from.

```css
 path { transition: fill .4s ease; }
 /* set fill for before and for during hover */
 #europe       path { fill: red; }
 #europe:hover path { fill: white; }
```

Here's a working [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/robbiewxyz/YLs6B/1/).

---

Or, doing it inline can be more convenient (`style=""`):

```
<path style="fill: #FAFAFA;" d="..."/>
```

Just in order for CSS to do your fading, it needs to handle the start and end values in CSS/inline style (as opposed to using the SVG `fill=` attribute).

Comment: A caveat (of sorts)  it seems that currentColor while it looks like a fill value is not treated as such.  Fill must be an explicit color value.

Comment: Doesn't seem to work with IE11, although that might be an IE bug without a workaround.  [https://connect.microsoft.com/IE/feedbackdetail/view/920928/ie-11-css-transition-property-not-working-for-svg-elements].  MS Edge works fine.

Answer (score 5):

Note that to style an SVG via CSS from within an HTML document, the SVG has to be embedded within the HTML of the page, i.e. it doesn't work by embedding it via `<object>` or `<img>` in HTML or via `background-image` etc. in CSS.

When it's embedded within your HTML, you can then style all its elements like you style HTML elements using a CSS selector to match the element(s) you want to style and applying the appropriate styles to it. Besides `fill` there is a bunch of other SVG attributes, which are also CSS properties. A list of them can be found in the [SVG specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG2/attindex.html#PresentationAttributes) or on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/Presentation).

In order for a transition to work, both the start and the end value have to be defined in CSS. So, instead of defining the fill color via the `fill` attribute (`fill="#FAFAFA"`), it needs to be defined either via the `style` attribute, which looks like this:

```
<path style="fill: #FAFAFA;" d="..."/>
```

or via a CSS rule packed in a `<style>` element within the SVG:

```
<style type="text/css">
  #south-america > path {
    fill: #FAFAFA;
  }
</style>
```

In both cases you can then transition the values via the CSS rule you mentioned.

Embedding the SVG within HTML has the advantage that you can do the styling from within the stylesheet you use for your HTML, so you can define styling that are shared between the HTML of your page and the embedded SVG.