# Fill SVG path with colour but on hover fade-in pattern

Tags: css, svg, css-transitions

I am trying to add an SVG image (in this case a flag of Belgium) as the fill of an SVG path (actually an ellipse). On hover, the ellipse's fill has to transition into red. In other words, the fill SVG has to 'fade out'. I tried it in a way I'd do it with CSS, but neither the SVG pattern nor the transition seem to work. I tried on Chrome and Firefox.

```css
svg ellipse {
  fill: url(#img1);
  transition: fill 400ms;
}

svg:hover ellipse {
  fill: red;
}
```

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns:ev="http://www.w3.org/2001/xml-events" version="1.1" height="480" width="640" viewBox="0 0 640 480">
  <defs>
    <pattern x="0" y="0" id="img1" height="480" width="640" viewBox="0 0 640 480">
        <g fill-rule="evenodd" stroke-width="1pt">
          <path d="M0 0h213.335v479.997H0z" />
          <path fill="#ffd90c" d="M213.335 0H426.67v479.997H213.335z" />
          <path fill="#f31830" d="M426.67 0h213.335v479.997H426.67z" />
        </g>
    </pattern>
  </defs>
  <rect fill="none" stroke="blue" x="1" y="1" width="640" height="480"/>
  <ellipse stroke="black" stroke-width="5" cx="400" cy="200" rx="350" ry="150" />
</svg>
```

Comment: I'm not sure if you can do it with an image, but doing it with an init fill to white rather than url(#img1) works.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20012240/using-css-to-transition-the-fill-property-of-an-svg-path-on-hover

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't transition `fill` like that because the two fills are not something that can be interpolated smoothly between.

What you need to do is have two versions of the ellipse, one on top of the other. Then either fade in or out the top one.

```css
.visible-on-hover {
  transition: opacity 400ms;
  opacity: 0;
}

.visible-on-hover:hover {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns:ev="http://www.w3.org/2001/xml-events" version="1.1" height="480" width="640" viewBox="0 0 640 480">
  <defs>
    <pattern x="0" y="0" id="img1" height="1" width="1"
             viewBox="0 0 640 480" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid slice">
        <g fill-rule="evenodd" stroke-width="1pt">
          <path d="M0 0h213.335v479.997H0z" />
          <path fill="#ffd90c" d="M213.335 0H426.67v479.997H213.335z" />
          <path fill="#f31830" d="M426.67 0h213.335v479.997H426.67z" />
        </g>
    </pattern>
  </defs>
  <rect fill="none" stroke="blue" x="1" y="1" width="640" height="480"/>
  <ellipse stroke="black" stroke-width="5" cx="400" cy="200" rx="350" ry="150" fill="url(#img1)"/>
  <ellipse stroke="black" stroke-width="5" cx="400" cy="200" rx="350" ry="150" fill="red" class="visible-on-hover"/>
</svg>
```

Comment: I still have one question, though. Why is the width/height specified as `1` for the pattern? When using `fill`, does it automatically cover the whole path? (Similar to how `background-size: cover` works?)

Comment: The default coordinate space for those attributes (`x`,`y`,`width`,`height`) is `patternUnits="objectBoundingBox"`. Which means they are relative to the element's bounding box.  (0,0) is the top left of the element; (1,1) is the bottom right of the element. [See the SVG spec section on Patterns](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/single-page.html#pservers-Patterns).