# Gradient over Instagram SVG of FontAwesome 5

Tags: css, svg, gradient, font-awesome-5

After upgrading to FontAwesome 5, I'm not able to color the svgs of FontAwesome.

This is my example: 
`⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀` https://codepen.io/shadrix/pen/GygdZr

Should be awesome if it worked like here: `⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀` https://codepen.io/immad-hamid/pen/jVNvQO  (Note: he used FontAwesome 4).

Comment: See https://github.com/FortAwesome/Font-Awesome/issues/11925 for reference.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Icons are no longer referenced as glyphs from a font, but injected as inline SVG. The content color of the icon is defined as `fill="currentColor"`.

The technique with setting the background and using `-webkit-background-clip` no longer works. Instead you can set the `color` property directly. Unfortunately, that is where you get into a bit of trouble because `color` does not support gradients. You can set `fill` instead, if you use a SVG gradient definition:

```css
body{
  background: black;
}
div {
  display:flex;
  justify-content:center;
  font-size:50px;
  color: white;
}

div:hover svg * {
  fill: url(#rg);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.1/js/all.js"></script>
<svg width="0" height="0">
  <radialGradient id="rg" r="150%" cx="30%" cy="107%">
    <stop stop-color="#fdf497" offset="0" />
    <stop stop-color="#fdf497" offset="0.05" />
    <stop stop-color="#fd5949" offset="0.45" />
    <stop stop-color="#d6249f" offset="0.6" />
    <stop stop-color="#285AEB" offset="0.9" />
  </radialGradient>
</svg>
<div>
<i class="fab fa-instagram" aria-hidden="true"></i>
</div>
```

THe `r` attribute for the gradient cannot be expressed in the same terms as in CSS, so it's a bit of an estimate here.

Note the selector `div:hover svg *`. with that, it overwrites the attribute on the element. It needs to reference the styled element directly, if inheriting that style, `fill="currentColor"` would have the higher specificity.

Comment: Wow you are awesome! Thank you!

Comment: Hi @ccprog, this answer is from a year ago, but I am having trouble using transition with this. How can I slowly transition this effect when I hover, instead of just instantly happening?

Comment: @ccprog Please disregard the last comment. I found the answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20012240/using-css-to-transition-the-fill-property-of-an-svg-path-on-hover

Comment: Could this be done on multiple icons but keeping the gradient consistent?

Comment: @Larm Yes, just move svg with gradient definition to the parent

Comment: A tip for anybody using angular out there. Here is the css selector that worked for me. ::ng-deep fa-icon svg[data-icon="instagram"] path {
  fill: url(#rg);
}

Comment: @ccprog Fire! How did you manage to reproduce Instagram's logo so perfectly with the `radialGradient` ? I assume you didn't just guess the values

Comment: The values were just copied from @PhilippMochine's pen. Where it says  "so it's a bit of an estimate here" I was a bit sloppy, a perfect copy would have been `r="127.8%"` for a square icon.

Comment: Worked great. Place the svg gradient in the html <head> then you can reference as needed in your style sheets

Comment: svg * was the piece I was missing from several similar examples

Answer (score 1):

I was able to make it work following this [answer](https://github.com/FortAwesome/Font-Awesome/issues/11925#issuecomment-749494279) to came up with the solution.
The key is to use the [mask feature](https://fontawesome.com/v5.15/how-to-use/on-the-web/styling/masking) in FontAwesome.
For instance, in [VueJs](https://github.com/FortAwesome/vue-fontawesome#advanced), for the instagram icon, we can use next code:

```
<font-awesome-icon :icon="['fab', 'instagram-square']" :class="icon" :mask="['fas', 'square-full']" />

.icon {
    color: white;
    background: radial-gradient(circle at 30% 107%, #fdf497 0%, #fdf497 5%, #fd5949 45%, #d6249f 60%, #285aeb 90%);
    background: -webkit-radial-gradient(circle at 30% 107%, #fdf497 0%, #fdf497 5%, #fd5949 45%, #d6249f 60%, #285aeb 90%);
}
```

All credits go for user sylvainDNS of the related comment.

Answer (score -4):

use like this

```
i.fab {
    background: linear-gradient(to right, #8490ff 0%, #62bdfc 70%);
    -webkit-background-clip: text;
    -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
}
```