# Transition <line> x1, y1, etc. attributes in SVG using CSS

Tags: css, svg, svelte

I have an inline SVG in a svelte component that contains some `<line>`s which change their `x1`, `x2`, `y1` and `y2` attributes based on state. I want to transition between the changes with CSS but it just jumps to the new state instead of transitioning. I would like if there's a native solution with CSS but I can also use svelte transitions.

```html
<button aria-pressed={active} on:click={toggleActive} {...$$restProps}>
    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 40 40">
        {#if active}
            <line x1="10" y1="10" x2="20" y2="20" />
            <line x1="10" y1="30" x2="30" y2="10" />
            <line x1="20" y1="20" x2="30" y2="30" />
        {:else}
            <line x1="5" y1="10" x2="35" y2="10" />
            <line x1="5" y1="20" x2="35" y2="20" />
            <line x1="5" y1="30" x2="35" y2="30" />
        {/if}
    </svg>
</button>
```

```css
svg line {
    stroke: black;
    stroke-width: 5;

    transition-property: x1, x2, y1, y2, all;
    transition-duration: 5s;
}
```

I have tried [using style attribute to set the coordinates based on this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20012937/13398668) and that didn't work either.

Comment: Line attributes are not CSS styles according to the SVG 2 specification. You'll need to redo this using SMIL.

Comment: ...or convert `<line x1="a" y1="b" x2="c" y1="d" />` to `<path d="M a b c d" />`. Then you can use `d: path('M a b c d')` in CSS.

Answer (score 0):

Even if the attributes could be transitioned, this would not work because the attributes are not changed: The previous elements are discarded and fully replaced.

One thing you could do is use `tweened` stores, though there are probably better methods. E.g.

```html
<script>
    import { cubicOut } from 'svelte/easing';
    import { tweened } from 'svelte/motion';

    let active = false;
    
    const stateActive = [10, 10, 20, 20, 10, 30, 30, 10, 20, 20, 30, 30];
    const stateInactive = [5, 10, 35, 10, 5, 20, 35, 20, 5, 30, 35, 30];
    
    const anim = stateInactive.map(v => tweened(v));
    const [v1, v2, v3, v4, v5, v6, v7, v8, v9, v10, v11, v12] = anim;
    $: anim.forEach((store, i) => store.set(
        (active ? stateActive : stateInactive)[i],
        { duration: 500, easing: cubicOut }
    ));
</script>

<button aria-pressed={active} on:click={() => active = !active}>
    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 40 40">
            <line x1={$v1} y1={$v2} x2={$v3} y2={$v4} />
            <line x1={$v5} y1={$v6} x2={$v7} y2={$v8} />
            <line x1={$v9} y1={$v10} x2={$v11} y2={$v12} />
    </svg>
</button>
```

[REPL](https://svelte.dev/repl/d8d46824ff7f4d329c2e27de4851778a?version=3.55.1)

Answer (score 0):

When conditionally setting `d=` on the same path element the transition seems to be working in Chrome(109) and Firefox(110) but not in Safari (16). The mentioned `d: path()` in the comments doesn't seem to be supported yet [caniuse](https://caniuse.com/?search=css%20d%3A%20path) Not sure if that's what's relevant in this case.

[REPL](https://svelte.dev/repl/3d26ba9a4bb74c0ba3171419ffb7c24d?version=3.55.1)

```
<script>
    let active = true
</script>

<button on:click={() => active = !active}>
    toggle
</button>

<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 40 40">
    <path d="{active ? 'M10 10 L20 20' : 'M5 10 L35 10'}" />
    <path d="{active ? 'M10 30 L30 10' : 'M5 20 L35 20'}" />
    <path d="{active ? 'M20 20 L30 30' : 'M5 30 L35 30'}" />
</svg>

<style>
    svg {
        width: 200px;
    }
    path {
        stroke: black;
        stroke-width: 5;
        transition: all 400ms;
    }
</style>
```

Comment: I know path elements can be transitioned/animated and I ended up using this approach, however it doesn't answer the original question about animating specifically svg attributes so I can't select this is as the accepted solution. In the future if svg does add support for this someone can add an answer for it and I will accept it. Thanks for your answer tho :)